# Google sign in unity

Tags: google-plus, unity-game-engine

Can anyone tell me (or suggest me a tutorial or something) to integrate google sign in my unity game...?

I searched but there are methods using OAuth. Is want something like Facebook SDK for unity.

Comment: Please check my article about this:

https://link.medium.com/msoezkqURgb

I have shared all the steps with screen shots

Answer (score 1):

You don't need google play games plugin and it doesnt work for iOS anyways if u don't have existing google play games account via ay android device in past.

However i am using this module available in Asset Store https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/94517

Comment: unbelievable, one would expect asset store full of google plus packages! this is literally the only package ever submitted and it's 2017! well thank you O_O

Comment: I know and i totally get the feeling. This is why my team took it out of our in-house project, cleaned it up for general purpose use and uploaded it. Took almost 3 weeks for an approval. I was surprised to see so many of my players telling me that they can't use facebook login at all. Let us know ur feedback, we will make a video available very soon to help with easier integration.